# How to limit the CPU usage of a dash loop that listens for a filesystem change?

Tags: loops, sh, cpu-usage, dash-shell

I wrote a loop in dash which waits for a file to appear in a certain location on the filesystem. But when it runs it takes up 50% of the CPU. I first lowered the CPU usage using a sleep command but the minimal sleep time in dash (1 second) is too long for me.

I need a way to sleep less than 1 second in bash or a different solution to lower the CPU usage of the loop. I only want to use programs that are installed by default on the most unix systems.

Comment: Instead of busy-waiting for the file to appear, use the file-system monitoring tools appropriate for your operating system (`inotify`, `fswatch`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Linux system, I can simply do

```
$ sleep 0.1
```

and it sleeps for 0.1 seconds. The `sleep` here lives in `/usr/bin/sleep`. I don't know which other unix-like systems support that, though.